# Each time accuracy differences with classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, supervised-learning

Each time when I run this code, accuracy comes out different. Can anyone please explain why? Am I missing something here ? Thanks in advance :)

Below is my code:

```
import scipy
import numpy
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = .5)

# Use a classifier of K-nearestNeibour
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
my_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()

my_classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)
print(predictions)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test,predictions))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) randomly splits the data into training and test sets, and so you will get different splits each time you run the script. If you want, there's a `random_state` parameter that you can set to some number and it will ensure that you get the same split each time you run the script:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = .5, random_state = 0)
```

This should give you an accuracy of `0.96` every time.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, appreciate your quick response. Yes, it's giving me 0.96 every time now.